# How to update individual column cell, row wise in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table variable `@temp` having empty columns `test001` till `test0048`.

I want to update each column individually for each row with some voltage values

Output should be like the below table:

```
test001    test002    test003 
  101.6       NULL      99.25
   NULL      102.5      89.45      
   NULL      68.45      103.0
```

I can do it using while loop and update cell for individual columns but while loop
takes more than 3 minutes to execute thousands of records.

Is there is any alternate way to update the columns row-wise?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What is your end goal with such a table?

Comment: In final output I need to display the different numeric voltage values for each column cell for each row.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to understand why you have a single diagonal stripe of data in your output table (as opposed to a single row).

Comment: @lc: I have edited my question if u can see this would be final output. I need to update each row at the end based on id.

Comment: Do you have a column or set of columns that can be used to identify unique records? Can you restructure the table at all?

Comment: Actually i forgot to mention the other part. I have one more table with repeating equipids. I need to  update the columns of the first record in first table with the column valuex of second table using join on equipid in both tables.

Comment: What does your input table look like? Where are you getting these values from?